# Line integral made of line segments

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals, parametrization

I want to find

$$\int_C (x^2 dx + y^2 dy + z^2 dz),$$

where $C$ is the curve consisting of line segments from $(0,1,0)$ to $(1,0,1)$ and then from $(1,0,1)$ to $(2,1,3)$.

I attach my working out in the below link that I have done - please take a look at it and tell me if I am wrong, or correct me.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Any response would be kindly appreciated.

-nomad609

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$C_1:\left\{\begin{matrix}
x=t & \\ 
y=1-t &, \ t \in\left [ 0, 1 \right ] \\ 
z=t & 
\end{matrix}\right.\\
C_2:\left\{\begin{matrix}
x=t+1 & \\ 
y=t &, \ t \in\left [ 0, 1 \right ] \\ 
z=2t+1 & 
\end{matrix}\right.\\
\mathrm{Then} \ \int_{C}{x^2dx+y^2dy+z^2dz}=\int_{C_1}{x^2dx+y^2dy+z^2dz}+\int_{C_2}{x^2dx+y^2dy+z^2dz}=\\
=\int_{0}^{1}\left ( t^2-\left ( 1-t \right )^2+t^2 \right )dt+\int_{0}^{1}{\left ( t+1 \right )^2+t^2+2\left ( 2t+1 \right )^2}dt=\frac{35}{3}$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I appreciate how quickly you have done it too, although my teacher said the answer was 35/3? I will attach my further working out too.

Comment: Can I kindly ask how you figure out what the parameters are and also how you choose the upper and lower limit to be 1 and 0? Thank you for your help.

Comment: There are some mistakes. I will edit.

Comment: Thank you I think this is correct, thanks

Comment: I have found the equation of a line passing through (0, 1, 0) and (1, 0, 1) (and similar for the (1, 0, 1) and (2, 1, 3)).For t = 0 we get (0, 1, 0) and for t = 1 – (1, 0, 1), so the parameter must be from 0 to 1.

Comment: Thank you for your post, and thank you for your help on this question :)